# Android barcode scanner to take only barcodes

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am using Android device that has built in barcode scanner and a keyboard. (Device is :Brand U8000S Android Barcode scanner)I am tryin to make an app that scans barcodes and prints out barcode in Toast after scanning. My problem is, that is possible to enter random keys and numbers on keyboard and it also prints that sequence of chars. I need help how to unable that, only to scan barcodes and go out of app. My code looks like this:

```
String barcode = "";
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

    if(e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
        char pressedKey = (char) e.getUnicodeChar();
        barcode += pressedKey;
    }

    if (e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP  && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
       // izvještaj.add(barcode);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "barcode--->>>" + barcode , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
                barcode ="";

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Talk to the device manufacturer and see if there is a way to disable the keyboard portion of the device or if there is some other API that you can use for interfacing with the device. If the barcode scanner portion simply emits keystrokes, it is unlikely that you will find a reliable way to tell those keystrokes apart from real keystrokes on the keyboard.

Comment: @CommonsWare you actually can by checking the speed of input

Comment: @SteelToe: I would not consider that to be a "reliable way", though it is possible that it is sufficient for some use cases.

Comment: @SteelToe how would you recommend to check speed input and get a reliable input value based on speed? Do you have an example of it ?

Comment: determine how fast the barcode scanner inputs characters, then if the speed of input between one character to another is longer then that, then that means it was handwritten from the keyboard and erase it

Comment: did you use laser to scan barcode or did that using camera?  I have the same device and I want to use laser to scan barcode?

Answer (score 1):

I have used dm77's barcodescanner in previous apps, this is a very good and comprehensive library and it provides decent guides for how to get up and running with simple bar code scanning. Another nice thing with this is that there is no keyboard interface to worry about too.

dm77 library:
https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Comment: I am new to all of this, is there any example how can I use that library in my app just for scaning barcodes ?

Comment: @Kurt

Add camera permission to your android manifest,

add the library you require to the build.gradle file

implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'

basic activity structure outlined in
https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

and there is even a nice sample project with this working for you to test and play with via
https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/tree/master/zxing-sample

Comment: this answer is a severe misunderstanding, He has a device with a built in barcode scanner and is not looking for a custom library

Comment: @SteelToe 
Thanks for you comment, I would disagree. I was aware that Kurt had a device with a built in barcode scanner and keyboard.

My suggestion of using the library was to point Kurt in the direction of a good set of resources that could help him implement the app he is looking to build arguably easier than having to determine input speeds of barcode scanner and keyboard as per your suggestion.

On reflection I suspect we both missed the mark with not making the obvious suggestion of disabling the keyboard.

Comment: I thought also about disabling the keyboard but how, it's a hard keyboard and if I disable it, would scan key work ?

Comment: @Kurt 
I am not sure how best to approach that one. I cannot see any reason why you wouldn't be able to ignore all key presses that weren't the scan button. As I say, the implementation though is not something I would know.

Comment: @justamarkprime valid point, thanks for explaining yourself, up voting